# Implementing the increment of a skipping iterator

Tags: c++, iterator

I would like to implement an operator over vector that would skip a certain value. This is what I wrote, with the problem I am facing commented:

```
template<class MyVector>
struct VectorSkipConstIterator : MyVector::const_iterator {
    using Base = typename MyVector::const_iterator;
    using ValueType = typename MyVector::value_type;

    VectorSkipConstIterator(const ValueType &skip) : Base(), skip_(skip){};
    VectorSkipConstIterator(Base it_, const ValueType &skip)
        : Base(it_), skip_(skip){};

    VectorSkipConstIterator &operator++() {
        do {
            Base::operator++();
        } while (/* have not reached the end */ && this->operator*() == skip_);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    ValueType skip_;
};
```

So, the problem is that operator++ has to stop somewhere (namely, at the end) even if the last value(s) in the vector need to be skipped. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Generally you check if you're at the end in the client code rather than in the iterator. And inheriting from an iterator is often A Bad Idea™, as it could just be a pointer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible way of achieving this is by simply passing the *end iterator* as an argument to `VectorSkipConstIterator`, and keeping it in a field.

```
template<class MyVector>
struct VectorSkipConstIterator : MyVector::const_iterator {
    using Base = typename MyVector::const_iterator;
    using ValueType = typename MyVector::value_type;

    VectorSkipConstIterator(const ValueType &skip, Base end) 
        : Base(), skip_(skip){}, end_(end)
    {
    }

    VectorSkipConstIterator(Base it_, const ValueType &skip, Base end)
        : Base(it_), skip_(skip), end_(end) 
    { 
    }

    VectorSkipConstIterator &operator++() {
        do {
            Base::operator++();
        } while (*this != end_ && this->operator*() == skip_);
        return *this;
    }
private:
    ValueType skip_;
    Base end_;
};
```

As TartanLlama said in the comments, inheriting from an iterator is not a good idea. Consider implementing your own iterator class from scratch, satisfying the [RandomAccessIterator](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/RandomAccessIterator) concept.

---

Another possible *(and in my opinion, better)* way of achieving what you desire is using an [*higher-order function*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function):

```
template <typename TContainer, typename TSkip, typename TF>
void forEachExcept(TContainer&& c, TSkip&& s, TF&& f)
{
    for(auto&& x : c)
    {
        if(x != s) f(x);
    }
}
```

You can use it as follows:

```
std::vector<int> v{1,2,5,1,6,2,1};

// skip all occurrences of `1`
forEachExcept(v, 1, [](auto x){ std::cout << x; });

// prints "2562"
```